# How to install a missing Xamarin SDK for an existing installation of Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

I want to develop a Mac app using Xamarin. However, when I open the New Project wizard, the Mac templates are nowhere to be found.

I saw ["Missing Project Templates for Mac Apps" on the Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98710/missing-project-templates-for-mac-apps),  but I could not find much else about this topic online, although the answer in that thread *did* clear up that I don't have the SDK, but (thankfully) my Xcode path is valid.

How can I install Xamarin.Mac (or any other Xamarin SDK) for an existing installation of Visual Studio for Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching online, I found [Install Visual Studio 2017 for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2017) in the Visual Studio docs, which finally cleared everything up:

> **Note**
>
> If you chose not to install a platform or tool during the original installation [...] you must run the [installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) again if you wish to add the components later.

(The installer itself is around 30 MB, so, not too bad.)

Comment: The progress bar got stuck at "Installing", but when I quit the installer (it'll save your progress, don't worry) it showed as installed, and now a Mac section shows up in the New Project wizard.